# vector.push_back(B) and vector.push_back(new A((*B))), why not act as the same?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have these two classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();

    virtual void TellMyName();
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    std::string szName;
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    void TellMyName();

    void SetName(std::string val){ szName = val; }
};
```

And this is my code:

```
void main()
{
    std::vector<A*> List_A;

    B* B_Instance = new B();
    B_Instance->SetName("B");

    List_A.push_back(B_Instance); // Way 1
    List_A.push_back(new A((*B_Instance))); // Way 2

    List_A[0]->TellMyName();
    List_A[1]->TellMyName();
}
```

`TellMyName()` is just going to prompt a message box. If I use "Way 1" there is no problem with it, but if I use "Way 2" it would prompt the message with no text and that means all members of the B class are empty like they're never being filled with anything. I solved this with the use of `std::shared_ptr`, but is there any other way to not use smart pointers because I have to implement this approach in a big project and there would be a lot of change and failure. And by the way, what's the cause to "Way 2"?

Comment: Read up on *object slicing*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't really informed about slicing thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List_A.push_back(new A((*B_Instance))); // Way 2
```

This line is not doing what you think it is.

You are creating a *new instance* of the class "A" on the heap by calling the default copy constructor generated by C++. That copy constructor uses the instance of B (treated as though it were an instance of A) and does a field-by-field copy, which in this case, does nothing.

You're essentially creating an empty instance of A and pushing it onto the list.

As many have mentioned, the formal term for this is called [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

> that means all members of the B class are empty like they're never being filled with anything

No. it doesn't mean they're empty.  To be empty, they'd have to be there in the first place.

`List_A[1]->TellMyName();` performs dynamic dispatch and ends up calling `A::TellMyName`, because `class A` is the actual type of the object.  Members of the `B` class don't even exist.

You've run into the slicing problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<A*> List_A;
// ...
List_A.push_back(new A((*B_Instance))); // Way 2
```

You are suffering from a form of [Object Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), sort of.

Object slicing happens when you instantiate (or assign) a base class with the values from a derived type, and lose -- or "slice off" -- all the stuff that was unique to the derived class.

Above, you are instantiating a `new A`, rather than a `new B`.  But since `B` is derived from `A`, you can simply instantiate a `new B` and cast the returned pointer to an `A*`:

```
List_A.push_back(new B(*B_Instance)); // Way 2
```

All of this being said, as an aside I would **strongly** advise you to consider refactoring your code to use smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling

```
List_A.push_back(new B((*B_Instance)));
```

As `B` inherits from `A` it can also be added to the list, but as the copy constructor of `B` will also copy all fields in `B`, it will work.

Calling `A`'s copy constructor doesn't copy the fields in `B`, as `A` doesn't "know" about `B`'s fields.